# What is a better mBaaS that supports offline sync and caching?

Tags: offline, mobile-application, hybrid-mobile-app, data-synchronization, mbaas

What is a better mBaaS that supports offline sync and caching?

I am evaluating several mBaaS solutions for my hybrid mobile app under development. I looked at Kinvey, Kii, buddy, and Telerik BackEnd platform. I have also came across some open source solutions like openmobster and dreamfactory. I am looking to store data in sql-lite on mobile app and then sync it back with an online data store. Kinvey has this support, but their pricing model (per user) is not suitable in my scenario. I can see that openmobster does this but, how is what I need to understand? Can I host in on Azure VM or something? Also please suggest if there is any other solution commercial/open source capable of doing offline sync and caching with push notifications and data storage?

Answer (score 0):

DreamFactory could be a good fit for your scenario. It is open source and comes with a full 30 days of free support. After which it's only like $25/month for a developer account - and this isn't even a requirement to use its product. It's specifically a support package.

To address your question a little more in-depth... I don't believe DreamFactory supports offline syncing at the moment, though they plan to very soon. In regards to sql-lite, DreamFactory's (DSP) product has a built in sql-lite driver to connect to that DB. However, it hasn't been tested enough for them to say it is a fully supported RDBMS. One of the beautiful things about DreamFactory is you're able to host the DSP (DreamFactory Service Platform) on Azure and Amazon EC2 instances (cloud solutions), host locally on your own server, or even use its own free hosted edition!

I would definitely take a little time to look into DF. It doesn't seem to me like you have much to lose. Especially, considering it's a free open-source product!

Feel free to ask me any questions you may have about DreamFactory!

-Mark